# Inject store into errorhandler class Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sentry

I am trying to implement sentry error handling into my application, now I have it set up and working as expected.. but now I want to be able to pass user information on the Sentry object for better error logging.

So I have the following setup

```
export class SentryErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
   userInfo: UserInfo;

   constructor(
     private _store: Store<AppState>
   ) {
     this.getUserInfo();
   }

   getUserInfo() {
    this._store.select('userInfo')
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.userInfo = result;
      });
  }

  handleError(err: any): void {
    Sentry.configureScope((scope) => {
      scope.setUser({
        email: this.userInfo?.emailAddress,
        id: this.userInfo?.id?,
      });
    });
    const eventId = Sentry.captureException(err.originalError || err);
    Sentry.showReportDialog({ eventId });
  }
}
```

and I am providing the error handler like so in my root module

```
// ...
{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: SentryErrorHandler }
// ...
```

but what happens is, when I start my application I get the following error

[image]

Obviously im doing something wrong here, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: does this error occurs in other classes if you try to inject `private _store: Store<AppState>` as well or only in this one?

Comment: @LeonardoAlves only this one

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening because without the `@Injectable` decorator Angular cannot wire up dependencies for the class (even using it in providers).

So all you have to do is add the `@Injectable()` decorator in your error class.

See a demo here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ctutia

Comment: Thanks, this has changed the error message to be `Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency!`